# How to set connection-timeout and socket-timeout with feign +http client?

Tags: spring-boot, httpclient, feign, openfeign

```
  @Bean
    public ApacheHttpClient client() {
        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(30)
                .setSocketTimeout(30).build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpClientObject = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .build();
        return new ApacheHttpClient(httpClientObject);
    }


@Autowired
    public HTTPRequestClient(Decoder decoder, Encoder encoder, ApacheHttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;

        setHttpRequestAdaptor(Feign.builder()
                .client(client)
                .encoder(encoder)
                .decoder(decoder)
                .logLevel(feign.Logger.Level.FULL)
                .target(Target.EmptyTarget.create(HTTPRequestAdaptor.class)));

    }
```

Connection timeout and socket time out is not working. Help required what properties work with feign http client?  I have been using

```
feign.httpclient.enabled=true
feign.httpclient.connection-timeout=2
```

but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `.options(new Request.Options(30, 30))`
to the feign builder

If that fails then maybe add the entire class to the quesion. The  ***this.client = client*** part of code looks a bit odd .