Running a large number of tests with gradlew
I have an application that is covered with about 500-700 tests, I need to run these tests using
./gradlew clean build

Some tests bring up context. No matter how many times I tried to change the settings of gradler tests in build.gradle, the tests kept failing with the error OutOfMemory, preliminary logs show the following:
[303.647s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2318: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 256 words
[303.647s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2321: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 256 words
[344.100s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2311: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 65536 words
[344.100s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2319: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 256 words
[346.936s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2311: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 21586 words
[346.936s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2312: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 256 words
[346.936s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2304: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 2750 words
[347.159s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2327: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 9370 words
[347.163s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2315: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 256 words
[347.163s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2323: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 256 words
[347.170s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2322: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 256 words
[347.410s][warning][gc,alloc] ClassGraph-worker-2310: Retried waiting for GCLocker too often allocating 256 words

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "FeignApacheHttpClientConfiguration.connectionManagerTimer"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "FeignApacheHttpClientConfiguration.connectionManagerTimer"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "FeignApacheHttpClientConfiguration.connectionManagerTimer"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp1060492372-285"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ClassGraph-worker-2318"


The build.gradle setup is like this
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    maxParallelForks = 1          
    forkEvery = 10             


    jvmArgs = [
            '-Xmx2g',
            '-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m',
            '-XX:+UseG1GC',
            '-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8m',
            '-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=20',
            '-XX:ConcGCThreads=1',
            '-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1',
            '-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300',
            '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError', 
            '-XX:HeapDumpPath=build/heapdumps',
            '-Xlog:gc*:build/gc.log'   
    ]
    systemProperties = [
            "feign.client.config.default.connectTimeout"   : "5000",
            "feign.client.config.default.readTimeout"      : "5000",
            "feign.httpclient.maxConnections"              : "3",
            "hikari.maximumPoolSize"                       : "2"
    ]
}

Сan anyone tell me how to set it up?

You should set time tout for OpenFeign likes this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873334/3728901

The clue of at here
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "FeignApacheHttpClientConfiguration.connectionManagerTimer"

You are focusing at increasing memory size, but, indeed, you need set time out for Open Feign globally or per client.
See

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#timeout-handling

https://www.baeldung.com/feign-timeout#globally

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873334/3728901



I increased the timeout fro feign client from 10 seconds to 50 seconds, still getting this error

No, you must reduce timeout. It will reduce memory.
